# Moderators get two close votes, bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, moderators

Take a look at [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/track-down-segmentation-faults-in-php). It looks like the following scenario happened:

- User votes to close a question
- User gains moderator privileges
- User votes to close again, probably forgetting that they already voted to close
- Question is closed via moderator super vote

Is this a bug? I would think the system would have just said "You have already voted to close this question - are you sure?", or at least combined the votes.

Comment: It would be nice if I could have seen that I'd already voted to close.  If it was there I didn't see it.  It would have affected my decision to close-vote again (only two other people though it was close-worthy, not three).  A couple days later, in hindsight, I probably should have un-closed the question when I saw what happened.

Comment: @Jason - I re-opened it and closed it again, so at least it doesn't show you closing it twice. I hope the OP doesn't think we were picking on him :/

Answer (score 2):

This is just too freakishly rare to even file as a bug IMO.